# Do I need to repeat the preposition "for" to keep this sentence parallel?

Tags: parallelism

Option A: Several Pentagon contractor firms are working on a new class of ventilator masks, not just for emergency and cleanup workers but to prepare for outbreaks of dangerous viruses and **for** still another growing threat: the accidental releases of nanoparticles, the infinitesimal and engineered fibers.

vs.

Option B: Several Pentagon contractor firms are working on a new class of ventilator masks, not just for emergency and cleanup workers but to prepare for outbreaks of dangerous viruses and still another growing threat: the accidental releases of nanoparticles, the infinitesimal and engineered fibers.

Is the "for" necessary? Can it be omitted?

Thank you!

Comment: Without the "for" it's unclear whether "still another .." is something to prepare for or another outbreak.

Comment: I do see the meaning/ambiguity issue. But it's not a parallelism issue, right?

Comment: @gmatgrammar It is a parallelism issue if you interpret it "the other" way—which is only possible without the **for**. So, depending on how you look at it, if you omit the preposition, it becomes a parallelism issue 50% of the time … You could omit the preposition and instead use *but to prepare for **not only** outbreaks of dangerous viruses, **but also** another growing threat …*

Comment: It's a poorly constructed sentence. Where did you find it?

Comment: Bill - It's a GMAT question, but I'm trying to just understand the grammar behind it. Jason - Got it, so if I omit the "for", it's a parallelism issue because it could be interpreted in two ways. Thank you all for your input!